# 10.3.0 Docker base images appear to be negatively impacted by recent 10.3.1 release

Tags: docker

A cross-thread to accompany a Sitecore support request. We are experiencing issues on our Docker-based environments. It seems to be closely related to the fact that Sitecore 10.3.1 was released today. As for that many docker base images received an update, and it appears that 10.3 images also received some kind of bump.

Regarding the original issue, currently, our environments (after pulling the configured Sitecore base images and deploying them) are not booting, and we are encountering this error:

**Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Could not find property 'alwaysExcludeVirtualFolder' on the object of type: Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.DefaultItemUrlBuilderOptions
Source: Sitecore.Kernel**

We are using 10.3-ltsc2022 as our base image and layering it with 10.3.1 pre-release images.

My current question is: Who else is experiencing similar issues today, and what mistake might we have made? As far as I am concerned, there was no way for us to anticipate the release of 10.3.1.

As for the solution: I am aware I can probably try to remove the delta images and upgrade to 10.3.1 images, however that should not be a regular process.

Comment: Hi Mathijs - SSE is not the format for a discussion based post on whether others are seeing the same issue. You would be better off taking this to the community forums or Sitecore Slack channels.

Comment: Fair enough. For those arriving on this page: using 10.3 as a base image without specifically specifying the 10.3.x release will automatically receive patch image updates. So we received a 10.3.1 base image. Our solution nuget packages were still pointing to 10.3.0 packages. Thus causing conflicts by sitecore.kernel 10.3.1 dll being overriden by 10.3.0 dll version. Solution: explicitly specify base image version, including patch nr.